# Is it possible set javascript prototype?

Tags: javascript

I use Array for instance.

```
let arr =[1, 2, 3, 4];


Array.prototype.a = function() {
    //code        
}
```

```
arr.a();  //return [2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Is it possible to create  prototype property.
And it's a function, it will double any element .

Comment: Yes, you may do so

Comment: @CertainPerformance - it's always good to get permission :p

Comment: I don't know how to get array

Comment: In 2020 unless you **must** develop pre-ES2015 code there is very little reason to use prototypes directly given now we have classes.

Comment: You *could* do that, but usually [you *should not*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice) (unless you do it on your own types).

Comment: @TTT hint: use `this`

Comment: Note that if you add something to `Array` prototype, then **all** arrays will have this `.a`, even ones that does not need it. It may lead to side effects

Comment: @zerkms `this` will reference to Array, cant not get variable

Comment: @TTT `this` references to the value, `[1, 2, 3, 4]` in your case.

Comment: @zerkms I think I make some mistake before. So this is not appropriate thing to do?

Comment: @TTT nope, instead - create a function that accepts an array and returns a new array.

Comment: It's better to subclass Array: `class MyArray extends Array{ static get [Symbol.species](){return MyArray} a(){ return this.map(e => e*2) } }`, then use it like `const arr = MyArray.from([1, 2, 3, 4]); console.log(arr.a())`

Answer (score -1):

Although you *can* modify the `.prototype` property of intrinsic (built-in) objects like `Array`, it is considered poor practice because other people might make assumptions that your change invalidates (eg. naming collisions). It's best to leave the intrinsics alone.

You can, however, use prototypical inheritance to extend intrinsic objects, without modifying them directly.

```js
class MyArray extends Array {
    static [Symbol.species] = Array
    *[Symbol.iterator]() {
        for(let x = 0; x < this.length; x++) { yield this[x]*2 }
    }
}

const log = console.log
const arr = new MyArray(1,2,3)
console.log([...arr]) // 2,4,6
log(arr.map((i) => i) instanceof MyArray) // false
log(arr.map((i) => i) instanceof Array) // true
```

In versions of JavaScript prior to ES2015, subclassing intrinsic objects like `Array` was [fraught with difficulty](http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array/). The closest you could come to it was something like this:

```js
function MyArray() {
    [].push.apply(this, arguments)
    //... plus tens of lines of code managing the `length` property 
}
Object.defineProperty(MyArray, Symbol.species, { value: Array })
MyArray.prototype = Object.create(Array.prototype)
MyArray.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = function*() {
    for (let x = 0; x < this.length; x++) {
        yield this[x] * 2
    }
}

const log = console.log
const arr = new MyArray(1,2,3)
log([...arr]) // 2,4,6
log(arr.map((el) => el) instanceof MyArray) // false
log(arr.map((el) => el) instanceof Array) // true
```